# Badly formatted TCP request

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, tcp

I establish a TCP connection to an Apple server from my windows computer using a WCF service in C#, and I receive a successful response and the server performs the necessary actions.

However, there is a problem when a Mac tries to connect to the same TCP Server after I connected to it, received my success response, and closed the connection. When the Mac tracks my requests, it shows a "badly formatted request" on my part, and the Mac is unable to perform the connection. I am still able to perform a TCP connection though and receive a successful response; however, according to the Mac tracking the connections to this server, all of my requests are "badly formatted."

How do I format my request correctly for connecting to an Apple server from Windows? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It's the great Microsoft conspiracy- annoy all of the Macs on the internet with those bad Redmond packets.  In all seriousness, does it explain how they are "badly formatted"?  Also, it's a little unclear how many machines are involved here.  Are we talking about 3?  One Apple Server, one Windows Client, and one Mac client?

Comment: yes 3 machines. thanks for the quick response. And it doesn't say how they are badly formatted. Is there like a tag I have to add at the end of each request I send when I try to connect to an apple server?

Comment: Does @noms question (and answer) here help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884959/exception-on-sslstream-authenticateasclient-the-message-was-badly-formatted

Comment: thanks, i did look at that. it didnt really understand what he/she meant by " I am using a Client certificate provided by Apple for push notifications."

Comment: Well, lets just start with this- is that the *same exact* error that you are seeing?  Or is yours different?

Comment: No it isnt the same exact error. All mine says is "Badly formatted request"