# Apple push notification server side in C#

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to .net and doing apn server side in C#. I'm using below code to push the messages to apple server.

```
    private void pushMessage()
    {
        int port = 2195;
        String deviceID = "4564c705 63b371aa 3811699e 1e4ac3d2 ba592b27 f2a5a613 d25cd035 xx213e54";
        String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";     // TEST
        //String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";           // REAL

        //        @"cert.p12";
        String certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Certi.p12");
        //X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, "");

        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);

        // _apnsStream = new SslStream(_apnsClient.GetStream(), false, validateServerCertificate, SelectLocalCertificate);
        //SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),null);

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, validateServerCertificate, SelectLocalCertificate);
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Default, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
            client.Close();
            return;
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
        writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
        writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)

        writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
        String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"hello\",\"badge\":0,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
        byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        writer.Write(b1);
        writer.Flush();
        byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
        sslStream.Write(array);
        sslStream.Flush();
        client.Close();
    }

    private string HexStringToByteArray(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

In execution, getting error like "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception".

[image]

[image]

I'm doing any wrong or missed here. Any certificate installation is required in windows? Please help me.

Comment: You need to click on `View Detail...` and tell us what the inner exception details are. You also have a few issues with your code - such as your `catch` is useless - all it will do is lose your stack trace and any code after `throw(e)` will not be executed (to name a couple).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884959/exception-on-sslstream-authenticateasclient-the-message-was-badly-formatted. The OP provides an answer for how they fixed the same issue.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use [**PushSharp**](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) as they have working examples that you can simply take and use...

Comment: You know that your exception handler is faulty, right? The client will never be closed, as `throw(e);` performs an immediated exit from the exception handler, thus the following two lines will never be called and the exception will be bubbled up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my code in PushNotification.class file

```
_certificate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p12FilePassword)? new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(p12File)): new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(p12File), p12FilePassword);
```

with

```
_certificate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p12FilePassword) ? new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(p12File)) : new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(p12File), p12FilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Answer (score -2):

so try....

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

....

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender,
                                             X509Certificate certificate,
                                             X509Chain chain,
                                             SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    return true;

  gerarLog("Certificate error: " + sslPolicyErrors);

  // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
  return false;
}

public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
  byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
  for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
  {
    string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
    HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
  return HexAsBytes;
}
```