# What things needed to add APN in .NET server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

As i have serch on google i am not sure that what things needed to implement APN in .NET server. In PHP server we create .PEM file but my .NET developer ask me for .P12 file so i am confuse.

As this nice Tutorial from [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) suggest what thing need to generate for PHP server which is .PEM file but what for .NET?

AS this tutorial suggest I have

- The CSR (of developer certificate)
- The private key as a p12 file (myapp.p12) (of development certificate)
- The SSL certificate, aps_development.cer

And i want to send this app for adHoc distribution so Is my p12 file will be from distribution certificate?

Or is tht i have to just give `.p12 file of my distribution certificate` and `ssl certificate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have all the things you need.

You have `aps_development.cer` add it in your keyChain Access. Which will display like this...

[image]

After that export this certificate in .p12 file

[image]

[image]

Add the password if you want

[image]

And than mac will ask your user password to verify

[image]

After you Do all this thing you got .p12 file of your SSL certificate. Now add this code to your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Dilip My token is: %@", deviceToken);
       //remember this token it will be used at server side
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Dilip Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Now you have two thing first is `certificate.p12` file and `Device Token` give it to your .net developer and you are done at your side you will get notification.

At server side This two link is really helpful to implement APN at server side.

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558398/apple-push-notification-server-side-in-c-sharp)
[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020762/does-anyone-know-how-to-write-an-apple-push-notification-provider-in-c)

And yes don't forget the token you get from apple will display like this  `<a3002e43 c1d2d80d 95b0a1a6 893b3f7c c410a489 747b933d 04551d68 688c6c65>` so you have to remove space and bracket that bcoz i have a problem when i have implemented APN first time bcoz of this space your string must be look like this `a3002e43c1d2d80d95b0a1a6893b3f7cc410a489747b933d04551d68688c6c65`.

Comment: Is there is no need to give password (which provide in image http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg8uv.png) to .net developer?

Comment: @AmitBattan no, No need to give your keychain password to developer.

Comment: @Dilip I tried this way to create certificate but fail to sent push notification, then I follow the following link https://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want a simple to-the-point solution and you don't mind using 3rd party software, you could take a look at [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp). This library is very popular and supports many customization options.

To generate the needed certificate and key, use [this tutorial](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp).

Hope it helps!