# Unable to get Push Notification using .Net server api

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, .net, push-notification

Push Notification is working fine when i use php server using `.pem` file but when i use `.p12` file for`.net` server it is not working and also i checked locally using APN Tester it works great.

i can't understand where is the problem at my side or `.net` server side. Please help me out.

this is a code which .net developer are using.

```
{
                Helper.WriteLog("Message :" + message);
                string deviceID = registrationKey; //"5712330e5fsdf2870c972d5c598ece88efbdac31baceed4961c5f4c53e9123594132";
                int port = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IosPort"]); //2195;
                String hostname = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];//"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
                string certPath = string.Empty;
                certPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePath"] + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateName"];//"~/Content/PushCertificateNew.p12";
                String certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(certPath);
                Helper.WriteLog("PushNotificationIOS certificatePath:" + certificatePath);
                string certPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"];
                //String certificatePath = @"C:\inetpub\ftproot\HQ\Content\PushCertificateNew.p12"; //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(certPath);
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
                Helper.WriteLog("Message :" + message);
                Helper.WriteLog(":" + deviceID);
                Helper.WriteLog("client after");

                try
                {

                    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), certPassword);
                    Helper.WriteLog("clientCertificate after");
                    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
                    Helper.WriteLog("certificatesCollection after");
                    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
                    Helper.WriteLog("sslStream after");

                    try
                    {
                        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Helper.WriteLog("sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient : TLS  " + ex.Message);
                    }

                    Helper.WriteLog("sslStream after");
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    Helper.WriteLog("MemoryStream");
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                    Helper.WriteLog("BinaryWriter");
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)32);
                    Helper.WriteLog("BinaryWriter Write");
                    writer.Write(StringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
                    String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":0,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
                    byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
                    Helper.WriteLog("Load Play sound"); ;
                    writer.Write(b1);
                    writer.Flush();
                    byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    Helper.WriteLog("Assign Memory stream"); ;
                    sslStream.Write(array);
                    Helper.WriteLog(array.Length.ToString());
                    sslStream.Flush();
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
                {
                    Helper.WriteLog("PushNotificationIOS catch  I :" + ex.Message);
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Helper.WriteLog("PushNotificationIOS catch  II :" + e.Message);
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714948/what-things-needed-to-add-apn-in-net-server